# The __getattribute__ method and descriptors

Tags: python, attributes, python-internals

according to this guide on python descriptors
https://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html

method objects in new style classes are implemented using descriptors in order to avoid special casing them in attribute lookup.

the way I understand this is that there is a method object type that implements `__get__` and returns a bound method object when called with an instance and an unbound method object when called with no instance and only a class. the article also states that this logic is implemented in the `object.__getattribute__` method. like so:

```
def __getattribute__(self, key):
    "Emulate type_getattro() in Objects/typeobject.c"
    v = object.__getattribute__(self, key)
    if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
       return v.__get__(None, self)
    return v
```

however `object.__getattribute__` is itself a method! so how is it bound to an object (without infinite recursion)? if it is special cased in the attribute lookup does that not defeat the purpose of removing the old style special casing?

Comment: "he way I understand this is that there is a method object type that implements __get__" => actually, it's the `function` type that is the descriptor here (cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, in CPython the default `__getattribute__` implementation is not a *Python* method, but is instead implemented in C. It can access object slots (entries in the C structure representing Python objects) directly, without bothering to go through the pesky attribute access routine.

Just because your *Python* code has to do this, doesn't mean the C code has to. :-)

If you do implement a Python `__getattribute__` method, just use `object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)`, or better still, `super().__getattribute__(attrname)` to access attributes on `self`. That way you won't hit recursion either.

In the CPython implementation, the attribute access is actually handled by the [`tp_getattro` slot](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) in the C type object, with a fallback to the [`tp_getattr` slot](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattr).

To be exhaustive and to fully expose what the C code does, when you use attribute access on an *instance*, here is the full set of functions called:

- Python translates attribute access to a call to the [`PyObject_GetAttr()` C function](https://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr). The [implementation for that function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/object.c#L929-L952) looks up the `tp_getattro` or `tp_getattr` slot for your class.
- The `object` type has [filled the `tp_getattro` slot](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/typeobject.c#L4790-L4830) with the [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/object.c#L1332-L1336), which delegates the call to [`_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/object.c#L1217-L1330) (with the `*dict` pointer set to `NULL` and the `suppress` argument set to `0`). This function is your `object.__getattribute__` method (a [special table](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/typeobject.c#L6933-L7118) maps between the name and the slots).
- This `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict` function can access the instance `__dict__` object through the [`tp_dict` slot](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict), but for *descriptors* (including methods), the [`_PyType_Lookup` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/typeobject.c#L3100-L3157) is used.
- `_PyType_Lookup` handles caching and delegates to [`find_name_in_mro`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/typeobject.c#L3038-L3098) on cache misses; the latter looks up attributes on the class (and superclasses). The code uses direct pointers to the `tp_dict` slot on each class in the MRO to reference class attributes.
- If a descriptor is found by `_PyType_Lookup` it is returned to `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict` and it calls the `tp_descr_get` function on that object (the `__get__` hook).

When you access an attribute on the *class itself*, instead of `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict`, the `type->tp_getattro` slot is instead serviced by the [`type_getattro()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc011b5190b63f0be561ddec38fc4cd9e60cbf6a/Objects/typeobject.c#L3187-L3274), which takes metaclasses into account too. This version calls `__get__` too, but leaves the instance parameter set to `None`.

Nowhere does this code have to recursively call `__getattribute__` to access the `__dict__` attribute, as it can simply reach into the C structures directly.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. do you mean to say that \_\_getattribute__ is not treated as a method of object and not looked up as a regular method? then who converts it from a function to a method?

Comment: @user3848844: `object.__getattribute__()` is a call to the unbound method of the built-in class `object`, so no, it is not looked up via what you call the regular method.

Comment: @user3848844: I've reworked this to be more accurate. `__getattribute__` is not implemented as Python code. It is a C function (no methods in C, C is not object oriented). The CPython interpreter, being coded in C, calls other C functions.

Comment: Side note: while the `hg.python.org` links still work, I wonder if this should be updated to use the github CPython. (But that's a lot of work...)

Comment: @torek: The [fate of hg.python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0512/#the-fate-of-hg-python-org) is still an open issue. For now, it'll continue to exist. I update answers to point to the github views as needed (usually when I come across an answer that uses the old links and recieved comments or a vote).

Comment: I've been trying to learn about attribute access and I have to say, your response was succinct and comprehensive. Thank you sir!