# Difference between __getattribute__ and obj.__dict__['x'] in python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I understand that in python, whenever you access a class/instance variable, it will call `__getattribute__` method to get the result. However I can also use `obj.__dict__['x']` directly, and get what I want.

I am a little confused about what is the difference? 
Also when I use `getattr(obj, name)`, is it calling `__getattribute__` or `obj.__dict__[name]` internally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute should clear your doubt.

Comment: @AashishP thanks for commenting. But that post explains difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`. It seems that `getattr` has little to do with `__getattr__`, so are you implying that `getattr` actually equals to `obj.__dict__[name]`?

Comment: Yeah, right. I tried to dig CPython source code and here is what I found, in plain language, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863787/python-the-getattribute-method-and-descriptors

Comment: Also, you can check C implementation of `getattr` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1364858e6ec7abfe04d92b7796ae8431eda87a7a/Python/bltinmodule.c#L985)

Comment: @AashishP thanks, I will read the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattribute__()` method is for lower level attribute processing.

Default implementation tries to find the name 
in the internal `__dict__` (or `__slots__`). If the attribute is not found, it calls `__getattr__()`.

UPDATE (as in the comment):

They are different ways for finding attributes in the Python data model. They are internal methods designed to fallback properly in any possible situation. A clue: "The machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`." from docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Does that mean `__getattribute__` will call try find attribute in `__dict__`, and do more things? In other word: `__getattribute__` is a superset of `__dict__` method.

Comment: They are different ways for finding attributes in the Python data model. They are internal methods designed to fallback properly in any possible situation. A clue: "The machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`."  from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Answer (score 2):

Attributes in `__dict__` are only a subset of all attributes that an object has.

Consider this class:

```
class C:
    ac = "+AC+" 
    def __init__(self):
        self.ab = "+AB+" 

    def show(self):
        pass
```

An instance `ic = C()` of this class will have attributes `'ab'`, `'ac'` and `'show'` (and few others). The `__gettattribute__` will find them all, but only the 'ab' is stored in the `ic.__dict__`. The other two can be found in `C.__dict__`.

Answer (score 0):

Not every python object has a dictionary where it's attributes are stored, there are slots, properties and attributes, that are calculated, wenn needed. You can also overwrite `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`. Attribute access is more complicated, than a simple dictionary lookup. So the normal way to access attribute is by

```
obj.x
```

wenn you have a variable with attribute name:

```
getattr(obj, name)
```

Normally you shouldn't use the internal attributes `__xxx__`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I read somewhere that when I use `obj.x`, it will can `__getattribute__`, if not found, `__getattr__` will be called. Where is the internal `__dict__` variable? If it is used when I access an instance attribute, and not recommended to use it directly, what is the point of it?