# Is type.__getattribute__ static?

Tags: python, methods

Consider the following

```
>>> class cls:
    pass

>>> obj=cls()
>>> obj.x=7
>>> cls.y=9
>>> obj.__getattribute__('x')
7
>>> cls.__getattribute__('y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    cls.__getattribute__('y')
TypeError: expected 1 argument, got 0
```

Why does `cls.__getattribute__` not return a bound method from `type`?

Comment: Do you understand [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol)? The equivalence you seem to be grasping for is `cls.__getattribute__.__get__(cls)('y')`.

Comment: yes I do, but are "special methods" implemented as non data descriptors as well? Also, descriptor protocol [*uses*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) ```__getattribute__``` for name look up. So this would be chicken and the egg type of issue

Comment: @wim I did some more digging and I actually [found something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863787/python-the-getattribute-method-and-descriptors) so I have a feeling that this question might not have a simple answer. It looks like it might be based on the C API and the notion of "staticmethod" might simply be not applicable. This makes sense, since in order to fetch ```__getattribute__```, it would need to be called to find itself.

Comment: Terminology nit: Python 3 doesn't really have bound and unbound methods; a "bound method" is an object of type `method`, and an "unbound method" is just the original `function` object. That said, `obj.__getattribute__` has type `method-wrapper` and `cls.__getattribute__` has type `wrapper_descriptor`, none of which answers your question, but indicates there is a *lot* of implementation-specific behavior going on at this level.

Comment: @chepner Python 3 *does* still [use the terminology "bound method"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6900f16d2207ca4fc252fa9d778ca0b13a3c95e0/Objects/classobject.c#L295).  It's "unbound method" that is gone / non-existent in Python 3 (but OP never mentioned those in the first place, so it's not really a fair nit imo).