# Why does property override object.__getattribute__?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I noticed that contrary to the `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators, the `property` decorator overrides the `object.__getattribute__` method:

```py
>>> list(vars(classmethod))
['__new__', '__repr__', '__get__', '__init__', '__func__', '__wrapped__', '__isabstractmethod__', '__dict__', '__doc__']
>>> list(vars(staticmethod))
['__new__', '__repr__', '__call__', '__get__', '__init__', '__func__', '__wrapped__', '__isabstractmethod__', '__dict__', '__doc__']
>>> list(vars(property))
['__new__', '__getattribute__', '__get__', '__set__', '__delete__', '__init__', 'getter', 'setter', 'deleter', '__set_name__', 'fget', 'fset', 'fdel', '__doc__', '__isabstractmethod__']
```

The functionality of the `property` decorator doesn’t seem to require this override (cf. the equivalent Python code in the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties)). So which behaviour exactly does this override implement? Please provide a link to the corresponding C code in the [CPython repository](https://github.com/python/cpython), and optionally an equivalent Python code.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but here seems to be some of the [relevant CPython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1eb950ca55b3e0b6524b3f03b0b519723916eca2/Python/specialize.c#L630).  I suspect the override for `__getattribute__` is necessary, because that's what gets called first (not `__getattr__`) when you use the dot operator to access an attribute, and the property descriptor itself is overriding standard attribute access so you can't overwrite the decorated method at runtime.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety That's for [optimization of `LOAD_ATTR`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/26759) that can be done for the builtin `property` type, further on they included [optimization for `__getattribute__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/93988), not related to how they are defined (`git blame` is a very useful tool to find all that out btw), and has nothing to do with the override for `__getattribute__` as that's not what's being defined in the code you have linked (my answer covered that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refresh yourself on what `__getattribute__` is and how this is implemented in CPython, please [refer to this very excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863898) first, as that answers contains all the detailed background information on what to look for in the CPython source, and the paragraphs below will reference those details without further explanations.

In CPython, all builtin types (e.g. `object`, `int`, `str`, `float`) all follow a standard way on how they are defined. These builtin types with their dunder methods are all slotted in the underlying C implementation, for example [`float`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/floatobject.c#L1890-L1931) simply reference the default [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/object.c#L1365C1-L1369) for `tp_getattro`, and this is exactly the same for [`property`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/descrobject.c#L1924-L1966).  Essentially, the descriptor howto guide is correct in omitting any references to `__getattribute__`, as its presence is nothing more than an artifact on how builtin types in Python are defined (i.e. they all point to the same generic implementation for ["the normal way of looking for object attributes"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) if it's just a pointer to the aptly named `PyObject_GenericGetAttr`).

As for why `classmethod` does not have `__getattribute__` appear as part of its `vars` output, that's because [the definition for `classmethod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/funcobject.c#L984-L1024) does not include `tp_getattro` nor `tp_getattr`, but it just means that its `__getattribute__` falls back to its parent's, which is `object.__getattribute__` (check in Python for output of `classmethod.__getattribute__ is object.__getattribute__`).  As for why `classmethod` is defined without the explicit linkage while various other builtin types define an explicit linkage to `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` (despite the outcome of either decisions being functionally the same in nearly all code usage), you may have to ask the developers themselves.

Addendum: though at some point 12 years ago (2012), around the time of Python 3.2 was being developed, `classmethod` *did* [have `tp_getattro` set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/84e821e961b5f0ea288f7f200902c24ec4f523bc/Objects/funcobject.c#L871-L911), but subsequent to that commit [`2cf936fe7a55`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2cf936fe7a5599dac368b4f04e5c5fc38db26c06) (included since 2.7.5 and 3.3.0a1) - the commit message has no hints as to why it was simply changed to "use defaults".  As for `float` and `property` type, the change was introduced way back in the merge commit [`6d6c1a35e08b`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6d6c1a35e08b95a83dbe47dbd9e6474daff00354) from nearly 22 years ago (2001) that brought in the changes outlined in [PEP-252](https://peps.python.org/pep-0252/) which is the descriptor protocol itself.  Note that it set all `tp_getattro` to `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` for standard types that didn't have it defined before (and likewise for `classmethod` which is where this type made its debut).

Comment: Thanks for the link to Martijn Pieters’s answer. Okay so overriding `__getattribute__` in built-in types by setting the `tp_getattro` field is the norm, even if it is to override it with the same method (I suppose it’s for optimizing method lookup). Then my question is why `__loader__`, `bool`, `classmethod`, `staticmethod`, and subclasses of `BaseException` do not do it?

Comment: As I said, you may have to ask the developers themselves (on why `classmethod` etc. don't do it).  One way you can verify the functionality being fundamentally the same is to build CPython yourself with `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` replaced with `0` for the type you want to test, but really I suspect it will not affect _normal_ Python code usage as long as this is not removed for `object` and/or `type`, so the normal `__mro__` resolution will find the copy for `__getattributes__` e.g. `float` or `property` at `object.__getattributes__`.

Comment: Included an addendum based on what anyone could have found from doing more `git blame` on the source code - the question you asked goes all the way back to when descriptor protocol itself was merged into CPython.

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/104772

Comment: As for `bool` type, it was [merged after](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5f8203679d113b3963180da6380ebd69f9f8cd44) the descriptor protocol, and subclasses of `BaseException` are, well, simple subclasses (not defined the same way as `BaseException` itself actually), generally you don't redefine `__getattribute__` for subclasses, right?

Comment: @GéryOgam Also honestly, I don't think that ticket will be well received, there is really no optimization with the change being proposed unless benchmarks are provided to prove that it does something.

Comment: ‘generally you don't redefine `__getattribute__` for subclasses, right?’ So you think the logic in the current codebase is to override `__getattribute__` only for *direct* subclasses of `object`?

Comment: ‘Also honestly, I don't think that ticket will be well received’ I think it should be allowed to ask questions in the Python community. ‘there is really no optimization with the change being proposed unless benchmarks are provided to prove that it does something’ Then how do you explain that almost all types override `__getattribute__`?

Comment: Because the types you are proposing to add this don't typically need attribute access - how often do real code do attribute access on `bool` or on the `classmethod` or `staticmethod` instance itself (not to mention it was removed for `classmethod` at some point)?  Also for anything but `BaseException` it complicates how they are defined.

Comment: We do attribute access on `classmethod` and `staticmethod` instances *all the time* since they are non-data descriptors (i.e. have a `__get__` method that is systematically accessed).

Comment: For `classmethod`. wouldn't it normally go through [`tp_descr_get`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/funcobject.c#L1213) anyway? Also for types that don't have that explicitly set, wouldn't it just have one anyway through the MRO? I don't know, maybe write a benchmark that can show this optimization benefit being a very real thing, this is just a very simple ask.

Comment: Looking at this deeper, maybe you might be right, [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/object.c#L1240)  above `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict` do suggest setting `tp_getattro`/`tp_setattro` out of consistency. For exceptions, [this set of macros](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Objects/exceptions.c#L489-L535) could be modified to include `tp_getattro` to have all builtin exceptions have this set wholesale.

Comment: ‘For `classmethod` wouldn't it normally go through `tp_descr_get` anyway?’ When you do `obj.attr`, `__getattribute__` is looked up in `type(obj).__mro__` and, if not overridden, `object.__getattribute__` is found. Then `object.__getattribute__(obj, 'attr')` is called which looks up a data descriptor `attr` on `type(obj)` and returns `attr.__get__(obj, type(obj))`, else an `attr` on `obj` and returns `attr`, else a non-data descriptor `attr` on `type(obj)` and returns `attr.__get__(obj, type(obj))`, else an `attr` on `type(obj)` and returns `attr`. `classmethod` is the non-data descriptor case.

Comment: Yeah, I did noticed that `tp_descr_get` is called from within `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict` anyway, which you also explained here through the Python terms.